# How do you get the ColdFusion 9 Mulit File Upload to work?

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

here is the code I have got so far.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
function onCancel() 
{ 
    ColdFusion.FileUpload.cancelUpload('myupload'); 
};
```

```
<cfform name="form01" action="#event.buildLink('login.fileAttachment')#"> 
<cfinput type="button" name="cancelupld" value="Cancel Upload" onclick="onCancel()"> 

</cfform>

<!---
<cffile action="uploadall" destination="D:\apache\htdocs\awng\upload" nameconflict="overwrite" />
<cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"> 
--->
```

What files do I need to make this work?

Comment: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/11/14/some-notes-on-cffileuploadall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<cffile action="uploadall"...>` is executed by the code that handles the form submission; in your case, the action created from this: `#event.buildLink('login.fileAttachment')#`.  So you will first need to include a file upload control within your form.  [`<cffileupload>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec18238-7fd0.html) may be a good choice for this.  Then, within the login.fileAttachment code, you'll execute your `<cffile action="uploadall">` tag, processing the selected files that were chosen on the form.

Further reading:

[cffileupload](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec18238-7fd0.html)

[cffile action="uploadall"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7388.html)